# String manipulation in Python

Tags: python

I have a **randomly** generated string from 6 letters in this form, example:

```
A' B F2 E' B2 A2 C' D2 C D' E2 F
```

Some letters have " ' " added to them some have number "2". What i want is to add letter "x" to every letter that is on its own.

So it would look like this:

```
A' Bx F2 E' B2 A2 C' D2 Cx D' E2 Fx
```

The trick is that it would add the "x" only to those letters that are on their own. No, Bx -> Bx2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transform your string into list with split()

```
s = """A' B F2 E' B2 A2 C' D2 C D' E2 F"""

L = s.split(' ')

for i in xrange(len(L)):
  if len(L[i]) == 1:
    L[i] += 'x'

str_out = ' '.join(L)
```

Answer (score 4):

The split-comprehend-join version:

```
' '.join(n+'x' if len(n)==1 else n for n in inputstr.split(' '))
```

The regex version:

```
>>> inputstr = "A' F B2 C"
>>> re.sub(r'([A-Z])(?=\s|$)', r'\1x', inputstr)
"A' Fx B2 Cx"
```

In essence, find any uppercase letter not followed by either a space or the end of the string, and replace it with that character followed by an `x`.

I ran a few tests with [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html); the former (list comprehension) appears to run slightly faster than the latter (about 15-20% faster on average). This does not appear to change no matter the number of replacements that need to be done (a string 10 times as long still has about the same ratio of processing time as the original).

Answer (score 3):

Ugly or Pythonic?

```
items = "A' B F2 E' B2 A2 C' D2 C D' E2 F".split()

itemsx = ((a+'x' if len(a)==1 else a) for a in items)
out = ' '.join(itemsx)
```

Answer (score 2):

With a regular expression,

```
import re
newstring = re.sub(r"\b(\w)(?![2'])", r'\1x', oldstring)
```

should be fine.  If you're allergic to `re`s,

```
news = ' '.join(x + 'x' if len(x)==1 else x for x in olds.split())
```

is a concise way of expressing a similar transformation (if length-one is really the only thing you need to check before appending 'x' to an item).

Comment: This actually fails due to the fact that `A'` is considered to have a word border between the `A` and the `'`. (Also, you forgot a capture group around the `\w`.)

Comment: Updated version still needs a tweak - the capture group should only be around the `\w`, and not the following character. Also, since it's trying to match a character after the `\w`, it won't work on a solo character at the end of a string.

Comment: Finally, since the behavior of `re.sub` is to replace the entire matched portion, not just the capture group, this will (unintentionally, I'm sure) strip the spaces after the characters it replaces.

Comment: @Dav, excellent analysis -- so I've edited again to switch to negative lookahead, which should take care of all the issues. +1 to each of your spot-on remarks!

Comment: You can also include a positive-lookbehind and drop the remembered group altogether: `re.sub(r"(?<=\b\w)(?![2'])", 'x', oldstring)`

Comment: @T, yes, but how is that supposed to be simpler or otherwise preferable?  It uses a longer pattern and two subtle RE concepts (instead of 1 subtle one and one very simple one).

Answer (score 1):

```
' '.join(n if len(n) == 2 else n + 'x' for n in s.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s="A' B F2 E' B2 A2 C' D2 C D' E2 F".split()
>>> import string
>>> letters=list(string.letters)
>>> for n,i in enumerate(s):
...     if i in letters:
...        s[n]=i+"x"
...
>>> ' '.join(s)
"A' Bx F2 E' B2 A2 C' D2 Cx D' E2 Fx"
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ' '.join((i+'x')[:2] for i in items.split())
"A' Bx F2 E' B2 A2 C' D2 Cx D' E2 Fx"
```